# How to allocate a bit field in the assembly programming language - NASM

Tags: assembly, numbers, nasm, bit, bit-fields

Can I allocate n length bit fields in memory?

If this answer is yes, can I make an operation such as addition and multiplication in this field?

Comment: AFAIK nasm only deals with bytes and larger.  If you want  bit fields you have to shift and mask them by hand.  Likewise x86 has no instructions for arithmetic on bitfields - you have to write more instructions to extract and pack them if needed.

Comment: So, how can I allocate bit field of length n? @NateEldredge

Comment: On its face, you can't.  You'll have to figure out what exactly you mean by that, in terms of bytes.

Comment: I did not understand why I could not allocate the bit field. Is it possible for me to do something like this ; access any bit in a byte ? @NateEldredge

Comment: You can allocate the bit field -- just allocate enough bytes to hold it (each byte holds 8 bits).  Also, you can pay attention to alignment, mandatory on some architectures, but optional on others.  So for example, if your bit field is 24 bits, then maybe allocate a 4 byte integer to hold it; that's rounding up the 24-bit size to 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks you, @ErikEidt. How do I multiplication the bıt fıelds I've allocate? MUL (NASM) seems to not work in this case.

Comment: The processor doesn't naturally handle bit fields, so if you have one in memory, you'll need to load bytes into a register and isolate the bit field's bits from the bits that aren't in the bit field.  Since we can only load bytes and a few multiples of bytes, there can be extra bits loaded from memory that belong to another bit field or are otherwise undesirable.  That's what the others are saying with shift and mask, etc..  In short, to store a bit field, simply round up to a full byte multiple, then in usage, strip off the unwanted bits..

Comment: Look at compiler output for a C function that does what you want, with a C struct using a bitfield.  e.g. `gcc -O2 -march=native` for example.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  That might be a good starting point to optimize from.  Note that you almost certainly don't want `mul`, usually just `imul reg, reg` after zero-extending the inputs to 32 or 64-bit, unless you actually want a double-width result split across two registers.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use words, double words and quardwords. There are bit test methods that could set bits in double words and up. Good luck finding an example or someone who actually knows how to do that though.

My thoughts on it:

```
;data
bitbuf: times 32 db 0

;r8 is index
mov cl, r8b
and cl, 7
mov al, 1
shl al, cl
mov rbx, r8
shr rbx, 3
mov rcx, bitbuf
xor byte [rcx + rbx], al
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `btc [bitbuf], rax` to use the whole RAX as a bit-index into the bitstring starting at `bitbuf`, flipping the bit at that index and setting CF = the old value (Bit Test and Complement).  Bit instructions with memory destination and register source are slower on current CPUs than using multiple instructions to do the indexing manually, though.  (Like 10 uops.  https://uops.info/).  Also, this only accesses a single bit, not a bit*field* like C `struct { int a:10, b:22; };`.  As discussed in comments, you just have to load the dword and extract in that case.

Comment: sorry, just put a working example

Comment: That's more instructions than necessary, e.g. `xor eax, eax` / `bts rax, r8` will set RAX = `1 << (r8 & 63)` in only 2 uops on Intel CPUs, 3 on AMD.  (BTS reg, reg is still fast, it's just the memory destination version that's slow because of the crazy-CISC bitstring semantics.)  Also, you start with `shr cl, 2` which discards to low 2 bits of the bit-index.  That seems wrong.  Also, you XOR an unaligned qword.  Probably better to use an aligned word or dword.  See https://godbolt.org/z/nh39TWxxb / [Sieve of Eratosthenes in x86 assembly](//codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/548870)

Comment: I meant to preform `and cl, 63` qword is a lot to xor, I will probably swap for a smaller thing. Not too hard to do.

Comment: `shr rax, cl` already masks the shift count with `&63`, there's no need to do it manually with `and`.  32-bit and narrower shifts mask the count with `&31`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr .  So yes, for `xor byte`, you do need to mask the count manually.